# VBA to open an Excel File

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to open an excel file in a folder of excel files using VBA. I direct my code to take the end user straight to the folder and allow him to choose the file from the dialog box. But I am not able to open the file even after selecting it from the dialog box.

My understanding of the problem is - I am missing out on the Command to open the file after selecting it.

Here is my Code,

```
thisYear = Year(Date)


'change the display name of the open file dialog
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Title = _
    "Select Input Report"

 'Remove all other filters
 Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Filters.Clear

 'Add a custom filter
 Call Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Filters.Add( _
     "Excel Files Only", "*.xls*")

     'Select the start folder
     Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen _
     ).InitialFileName = "\\driveA\Reports\" & thisYear & ""
```

Please kindly share your thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836226.aspx) will get you started

Comment: @Kyle I am able to select the file from the dialog box but still the file doesn't get opened. I wonder there is a separate command or a line of code to open the file that I am selecting from the dialog box.

Comment: Did you read the link and look at the related example? It shows you how to extract the path of the selected file, and then you can simply use `Workbooks.Open()` with that path.

Comment: @Kyle Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you only let selecting one file (i.e. `AllowMultiSelect = False`).

```
 Dim file As String
 Dim myWbk As Workbook     

 file = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1) 

 Set myWbk = Workbooks.Open(file)
```

First line gets the path of the selected file and then second line opens it. Add this to the end of your code.

Comment: Yes, Thanks @Masoud. I was looking to open a single file only.