# Bad file name or number vba

Tags: excel, vba

my code keeps getting a bad file name or number error and I can't figure out what the issue is, any help would be appreciated! I'm trying to store the filepath based on user selection as a variable which I can reference later in a vlookup.  Below is my code, I can't figure out what's wrong but I used the pasted code in another macro which compiled fine.

```
sub edits
dim xpath and xfile as string
xPath = NewPath 'Newpath function executes
xfile = Dir$(xPath & "*.xlsm*", vbNormal) 'error here 
Set SourceBook = Workbooks.Open(xPath & xfile)
End Sub

Function NewPath() As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .ButtonName = "Choose a file"
        .Title = "Previous File"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show Then xPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With
End Function
```

Below is the code I've used which has compiled, it has the user select a folder instead of a file

```
sub something
dim xpath and xfile as string
xPath = NewPath
If Not strPath = vbNullString Then
xfile = Dir$(xPath & "*.xlsm", vbNormal)
Do While Not xfile = vbNullString
    'some code
    Set SourceBook = Workbooks.Open(xPath & xfile)
    SourceBook.Close False
    xfile = Dir$()
    Loop
End If
End Sub

Function NewPath() As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .ButtonName = "Choose a folder"
        .Title = "Folder Picker"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show Then NewPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With
 End Function
```

Comment: Where do you get an error?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2, At this line : xfile = Dir$(xPath & "*.xlsm*", vbNormal)

Comment: So you have *If .Show Then NewPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"* in your function, and subsequently redefine xpath as newpath in your subroutine which is then used in the xfile... so are you not getting a correct naming?  that's be like %userprofile%\cat.xlsm\.xlsm, according to xfile

Comment: The `msoFileDialogOpen` File Dialog returns the full path of a file - so it would be incorrect to add the extension `.xlsm` to its results

Comment: @BigBen hey I tried removing the extension so that it is just xfile = Dir$(xPath, vbNormal)  but I still get that error

Comment: Did you get rid of the backslash on the end as well? .... `If .Show Then xPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"`?

Comment: @BigBen So now I get a Run-time error '1004': Microsoft Excel cannot access the file ... There are several possible reasons: The file name or path doesn't exist. I don't understand why I'm getting this error since the file is there...

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating this - see [VBA to open an excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43620990/vba-to-open-an-excel-file). No need for `Dir`.